# What is the replacement for DrawThemeTextEx on Windows 8 and 10?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, gdi, windows-10

I'm using the "[glass effect](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15770/Vista-Goodies-in-C-Using-Glass-in-Your-UI)" to render the background of my window. Because of that I need to render the text with a glow behind it. In Windows 7 I used the [DrawThemeTextEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773317%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for that, which made the text quite readable on the dark background:

[image]

But if I run the same app on the same dark background in Windows 10, DrawThemeTextEx doesn't seem to add any glow to it:

[image]

Believe it or not, the text is still there :)

So I was curious how do I make that API render the glow behind it on Windows 10?

Comment: Just give up on glass effects. Microsoft clearly have.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: I thought they reinstated it back in Windows 10...

Comment: Nope, Windows 10 is wall-to-wall solid white. No glass in sight.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Hmm. My copy has a semi-transparent taskbar and that new "Action Center" that comes out from the right.

Comment: the glass in win10 is a new kind of glass: https://github.com/riverar/sample-win10-aeroglass/commit/3df0862a1ef7b51ca8614daf75b9f927d6a4a4b8#diff-6499fb3608f6070bba18c8e1f33f1b60R8

Comment: @magicandre1981: Yes, I know that. The question is why doesn't it "honor" the glow behind text?

Comment: because the API is dead since Windows 8.

Comment: Is there some other API that can be used instead?